# AngularJs not working in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

It works fine when the page is opened normally but does not when its open as a modal.  The expressions show up as literal text. Do I have to use the Angular Bootstrap UI?  Does anyone have an example of how this is done?  My modals are stored as partials

Comment: This is exactly what i am using for my modals, its just that angularjs code wont run in these kinds of modals for some reason. http://www.fabro.pl/Download.aspx?S=Bootstrap%20modal%20MVC%205

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

its simple to use, just include the javascript, a little CCS and  `angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);`

Once added you have todo some things a different way, plenty of examples on the angular site. One of the main issue it solves is problems when href # is used.

This may not be the fix for you, but you should be using it. Do you have a plunk?

Comment: steve, can you have a look at this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640905/angularjs-not-working-on-bootstrap-modals

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Boostrap as a dependency to the angular Application,

```
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and App,

```
angular.module('modalTest',['ui.bootstrap','dialogs'])
```

Here is an existing [`CodePen`](http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/ALsdF)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, libraries exist to bring bootstrap into the angular world. Keep in mind, a lot of things are done differently when using them in how you set up your DOM. Bootstrap uses a lot of things in `location.hash` for controls, which conflicts with angular routing.

The issue is that when Bootstrap pops up a modal, angular has no idea that happened, and that it has a new part of the DOM to compile. If you don't want to pull in the angular bootstrap library (which is pretty good, and should be used if your starting a new page from scratch with the two), you can use `$compile` linked with a callback into angular (probably via a factory you make) to manually compile what you need.

Comment: I am still very much stuck with this issue